# Poner un div fijo centrado y ocultarlo en el encabezado y en el pie de la página

Tags: jquery, css

Tengo un div fijo ubicado debajo de la página (`<div class="Letras">`). Lo que no puedo lograr con dicho div es **que el mismo me quede centrado**. Además de eso, me gustaría que el div sólo se empiece a mostrar cuando el usuario abandona el encabezado de página (bajando haciendo scroll) y sacarlo antes de que llegue al final (al footer). En definitiva, **que se vea siempre cuando está en el medio de la página** (que es dónde está el contenido para el cual hará uso de ese div fijo).

Si sirve de ayuda acá les dejo algo del [Código](https://codepen.io/DamianMDQ/pen/wbgBbx) que arme en codepen. Deben moverse un poco hacia abajo para que aparezca el div. Ahí también pueden leer los comentarios que deje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude solucionar ambos problemas que tenía con el div fijado al pie de la página.

**1) Centrar el div fijo al pie de la página**: Tuve que agregar un div contenedor (`<div class="Container">`) con las siguientes propiedades:

```
.Container 
{
    z-index:999;   
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

y después al div que está dentro (`<div class="Letras">`) del `<div class="Container">` le puse las siguientes propiedades:

```
.Letras {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Dentro del html en el body lo tengo así `<div class="Container"><div class="Letras"><ul id="alfabeto"></ul></div></div>`. Lo bueno es que me ha funcionado en diferentes navegadores y resoluciones de pantalla. Siempre me queda centrado.
Esto se puede visualizar [desde acá](https://codepen.io/DamianMDQ/pen/wbgBbx), el código que he modificado en Codepen.

**1) Ocultar el div en el encabeza y pie de página**: Acá ya pude lograr que sólo se muestre el div con las letras del alfabeto cuando se hace scroll y en determinas partes de la página (por ejemplo no se visualiza ni en la cabecera ni en el pie de la página).
Para este caso trabajo con `Jquery` y con la función `scroll`. La parte del código que hace el trabajo es el siguiente:

```
$(function() {
...
...
    $('.Letras').hide();
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         var windowPosY = $(window).scrollTop();
         var Sup = $("#ContIT").offset().top;
         var Inf = $("#Barra").offset().top; 
         if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 481px)").matches) {
            if (windowPosY >= Sup + 100 && windowPosY < Inf - 700){ 
                if($('img#Fle-Mostrar').css('display') == 'none'){
                    $('.Letras').show();}else{$("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","block");}         
            }else{
                $('.Letras').hide();
                $("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","none");
                }
        }
         else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1280px)").matches) {
             if (windowPosY < Inf - 600){   
                if($('img#Fle-Mostrar').css('display') == 'none'){
                    $('.Letras').show();}else{$("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","block");}         
            }else{
                $('.Letras').hide();
                $("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","none");
            }
         }
         else {
             if (windowPosY < Inf - 800){   
                if($('img#Fle-Mostrar').css('display') == 'none'){
                    $('.Letras').show();}else{$("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","block");}         
            }else{
                $('.Letras').hide();
                $("img#Fle-Mostrar").css("display","none");
            }
         }
    });
  });
```

Primero oculto el div en donde estan las letras (`$('.Letras').hide()`) y luego dentro de la función del `scroll` empiezo a trabajar con diferentes valores: el que se obtienen al hacer el scroll en la página (`$(window).scrollTop()`), el del div de cabecera (`$("#ContIT")`) y el div que está al pie (`$("#Barra")`).

Los if de `window.matchMedia` me permiten trabajar según el dispositivo y su resolución, ya que va a cambiar las dimensiones y sus valores dependiendo el dispositivo utilizado. Luego muestro o oculto el div según los valores que vaya teniendo las variables.

**Nota**: En la parte del código aparece otro elemento (`$("img#Fle-Mostrar")`, siendo sólo una imagen de flecha) que es el que reemplaza al del alfabeto (`$('.Letras')`) cuando el anterior se oculta y viceversa. Este no viene al caso para el problema planteado.